# View model in Asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

```
public ActionResult listItems()
{
    var getTopStories =  DB.posts.Where(x => x.post_type == "blog").OrderByDescending(x => x.id).Take(4).ToList();

    return View(getTopStories);
}
public ActionResult singleItem()
{
    var single = DB.posts.Where(x => x.post_type == "paper").OrderByDescending(x => x.id).First();
    return View(single);

}
```

As my above code i have two action result Method but both have different conditions so i want to show both method data on View without using View Bag how i can do this ?

Comment: You can use viewmodel then

Comment: how to use view model ? because i have only single post model

Comment: you can map your model from view model in post action result.

Comment: please give m simple example acording to my code because i new on asp.mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's assume you have a Post class with some properties(id,name, etc.). First create a new class like this,

```
public class PostViewModel
{
    public List<Post> PostList { get; set; }
    public Post SinglePost { get; set; }
}
```

Now in your your action result (Don't need two separate action result) map your data in view model like this

```
public ActionResult SingleAndlistPost()
{
           PostViewModel model=new PostViewModel
            {
                PostList = DB.posts.Where(x => x.post_type == "blog").OrderByDescending(x => x.id).Take(4).ToList(),
                SinglePost = DB.posts.Where(x => x.post_type == "paper").OrderByDescending(x => x.id).First()
            };

           return View(model);
}
```

Finally in your cshtml view access data like this

```
@model YourProject.YourModel.PostViewModel 
//.......

<p>@Model.SinglePost.MyProperty</p>

foreach (var list in Model.PostList)
{
    <p>@list.MyProperty</p>
}
```

Comment: If you have any issue with post please let me know to help you out

Comment: Thanks Bro! It helped me a lot and clear my concept about view-model .You are great!

Comment: one thing more please .... public List<post> PostList { get; set; }
        public post singlePost { get; set; }
        public List<post> toprecent { get; set; } can i view data from 3rd list on same viewmodel ? i tried but get a error i think the 3rd one override on first one .

Comment: Yes, you can use multiple lists of same type with different name. your code looks like okay and it will not override your data unless you have different issues like, same query, mistake in for loop in view etc.